# Set icon to the group in options menu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I want to show a group of options in the menu, and need to change the standard three-lines icon to my own image. How can I achieve this? Group doesn't have an @icon option, unfortunately

[image]

**menu.xml**

```
<item 
    android:icon="@drawable/settings">

    <group android:menuCategory="container">
        <item
        android:id="@+id/action_mute"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_mute"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_add"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_people"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_people"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_more"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_more"/>  
    </group>    
</item>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called `overflow button`, if you want to change it you need to declare it in your `style.xml` located in the **values** folder.

Add this in your `style.xml`

```
<style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
</style>
```

after you need to call it from you `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="//theme of your actionbar">
   <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```